# Segmentation fault issue with isdigit

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I have a function that will check if a string has any non-digit chars in it and returns a bool. But when I run it thru a debugger I get a segmentation fault.

Here is the function in question.

```
bool checkInt(string myString){
for (int i=0; i<myString.length; i++){
    if (!isdigit(myString[i])){
        return false;
    };
    return true;
}
```

I get the segfault on lines two and three on the for and if statements 
if it helps here is the build log as well.

```
C:\Users\conner\Desktop\programing\for dummes\main.cpp: In function 'bool checkInt(std::string)':
C:\Users\conner\Desktop\programing\for dummes\main.cpp:78:30: error: invalid use of member function (did you forget the '()' ?)
C:\Users\conner\Desktop\programing\for dummes\main.cpp:84:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

Comment: This doesn't even build. How did you get a segfault?

Comment: I debugged it anyways and I had the segfault before some small changes that caused the failed build.

Comment: @toa697 It is interesting do you read usually only one post or you read all answers to your question?:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` is being compared as greater than, not less than, in the for loop.  This is causing access outside of the string buffer inside of `myString[i]` and a segmentation fault. Also, `myString.length()` should be used instead of `myString.length`. (As per manlio's comment).

Comment: Also it should be myString.length()

Answer (score 2):

A compiler error is not a "segfault". The error messages are telling you that there is a mistake in your source code, and the compiler can't finish compiling your program.

In your case, the error appears to be in the use of `myString.length`. This should be `myString.length()` because `length` is a member function and must be called (with `()`).

Comment: As I said before on the comments for the question. I had the segfault before the build errors occurred.

Comment: That may be so, but you didn't get the segfault from *this* program because this program does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Change to `i < myString.length();`

Answer (score 0):

You got the segmentation fault because it seems you run an object module that was built with compilation errors. For example MS VC++ allows to do so.

Your function has a compilation error. Instead of correct syntax of calling member function length as

```
myString.length()
```

you wrote

```
myString.length
```

Also the condition in the loop statement is invalid
Instead of

```
for (int i=0; i>myString.length; i++){
```

there should be at least

```
for (int i=0; i < myString.length; i++){
```

The correct function could look as

```
bool checkInt( const string &myString )
{
   string::size_type i = 0;

   while ( i < myString.length() && isdigit( myString[i] ) ) ++i;

   return ( i == myString.length() );
}
```

Also you could use standard algorithm `std::all_of` declared in header `<algorithm>`

For example

```
inline bool checkInt( const string &myString )
{
    return std::all_of( myString.begin(), myString.end(), 
                        []( char c ) { return ::isdigit( c ); } );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code misses a curly bracket. You should test whether `i` is less than `myString.length`, rather than greater. The semicolon after closing the if branch isn't needed.

```
bool checkInt(string myString)
{
    for (int i=0; i < myString.length(); i++)
        if(isdigit(myString[i]))
            return false;

    return true;
}
```